# google-charts-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization, nameerror

hello I have been reading about how to make graphs using google-charts-on-rails, I already installed the plugin but I don`t know why shows me this error:

```
NameError in TankingLogsController#index

uninitialized constant TankingLogsController::GoogleChart
```

this is my indes.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
 <%= image_tag @bar %>

  <h1>Listing Tankings</h1>
  <% if @tankinglog.count<1 %>
    <p>
    There are no tankings for this car. Do you want to <%= link_to 'create a new tanking', new_user_car_tanking_log_path(@user, @car)%>
    </p>
  <% else %>
    <table class="table table-condensed">
      <tr>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Gallon</th>
        <th>Km</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Gas Station's id</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <% @tankinglog.each do |tankinglog| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= tankinglog.cost %></td>
          <td><%= tankinglog.gallon %></td>
          <td><%= tankinglog.km %></td>
          <td><%= tankinglog.date %></td>
          <td><%= tankinglog.gas_station_id %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
    <br />
    <%= link_to 'New tanking', new_user_car_tanking_log_path(@user, @car), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  <br />
  <br />
  <%= link_to 'back', user_cars_path(current_user), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
```

here is my controller

```
class TankingLogsController < ApplicationController

....


  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) 
    @car = @user.cars.find(params[:car_id])    
    @tankinglog = @car.tanking_logs.all
    @bar = GoogleChart.pie(['1997',10],['1998',20],['1999',40],['2000',30]).to_url
  end
end
```

my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'pg', '0.13.2'
gem 'devise', '2.0.4'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '2.0.6'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem "rspec", "~> 2.10.0"
gem 'simplecov', :require => false, :group => :test
gem 'gchart'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure the gem is in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'google-charts-on-rails'
```

Otherwise the app will not use the gem, even if you have it installed on your system.

Comment: I put that line in my Gemfile and I got this error :Could not find gem 'google-charts-on-rails (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.

Comment: My bad - I've assumed that this is a gem you are using - this will not work... In that case, I'd recommend using a gem anyway that gives you similar functionality - maybe googlecharts: [http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/]

Comment: I followed the steps of [http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/] but nothig change except the error:ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Gchart

Comment: Did you add `gem 'gchart'` to the Gemfile?

Comment: hmmm... Then I'm not sure - it sounds like neither are installing properly. Maybe try running `bundle install` then open the page again. (I'm assuming you updated the code in index.html.erb with the proper syntax for the gchart gem...)

Comment: that line "<%@bar = Gchart.bar(:data => [[300, 100, 30, 200], [100, 200, 300, 10]], :bar_colors => 'FF0000,00FF00')%>" is in the view or I must to create a controller and type the line??

Comment: It should display either way, but from an MVC perspective, it should probably be in the controller. Not having a controller may be your problem though - I don't know if rails works with pages that don't have one!

Comment: Try adding `source 'http://gems.github.com/'` to the Gemfile as well - I don't think googlecharts is on rubygems

Answer (score 2):

I solved by restarting the server.

Comment: That's become the web programmer's version of "have you tried turning it off and on again?" - solves 90% of problems, done 10% of the time!

Comment: Was having a problem with a different charting plugin, this solved it. Thanks.